# How do you change the color of the DatePicker control for .NET MAUI

Tags: .net, datepicker, maui

I am using .NET MAUI and i want to change the color of the DatePicker. in Styles.Xaml, it has the following:

```
<Style TargetType="DatePicker">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource LightGray}, Dark={StaticResource DarkGray}}" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

How do I change the default colors of it

Comment: What's the color of it you want to change? Text color or Background color or something else? There are two properties named textcolor and background color we can set in xaml.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<Style x:Key="DatePickerBackground" TargetType="DatePicker">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource PrimaryInputControlBackground}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
</Style>
```

Or if you want to chnage it directly:

```
<Style x:Key="DatePickerBackground" TargetType="DatePicker">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I still have the default purple colour.

Comment: I have tested - it worked for me. Please create your question if needed with your example code that not working